# How to get JSON format data in python

Tags: python, json, django

I calling below code line its working fine

```
return HttpResponse( json.dumps(rows), content_type='application/json')
```

> getting output like below:

```
["f8823b39f5", "000002de", "176", "STAT", "NY"]
```

I want JSON fromat because of that i run below code:

```
return HttpResponse( json.dumps(dict(rows)), content_type='application/json')
```

> Getting below error:

```
'dict' object is not callable
```

> ```
> Excepting output like below:
> ```

```
{"earning1": "f8823b39f5", "earning2": "000002de", ...}
```

Please help me. How to solve this problem.

Comment: Your question is hard to understand. Where did "earning1" and "earning2" come from?

Comment: more code please. with this is impossible to know. Anyway, json can parser a list so it doesn't show any problem.

Comment: Almost certainly you've given something else the name `dict` which has overwritten the built-in function.

Comment: In addition to what @Daniel has mentioned - given your example of `rows` - that's not valid input to `dict` even when you aren't shadowing the builtin.

Answer (score 0):

Use django serializers to convert django objects to other formats

```
return HttpResponse(serializers.serialize("json", rows))
```

Read more here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/serialization/

Answer (score -1):

Try this instead.

jsonToPython = json.loads(jsonData)
print(jsonToPython)

Comment: `json.loads` is the opposite of `json.dumps` - I don't see how this helps the OP?

Answer (score -1):

```
import json
import requests

headersGet = {'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8', 'Accept': 'application/json'}

 p = requests.get("URL",headers=headersGet)
 json_data = p.json()
print(json_data)
```